# Преобразование из префиксной записи в инфиксную

Tags: c#, алгоритм, pascal, преобразование, польская-запись

Как преобразовать префиксную запись (польскую нотацию) в инфиксную. Запись может содержать: '(', ')', '+', '-', '*', '/', '0..9', 'a..z'. Подскажите алгоритм решения данной задачи (описание, Pascal, C#), какие структуры данных нужно использовать?

Comment: "Если оператор имеет фиксированную арность, то в такой записи будут отсутствовать круглые скобки и она может быть интерпретирована без неоднозначности."

Comment: @PashaPash: По идее, нет, она вроде бы и называется бесскобочной.

Comment: @VladD бесскобочная - это постфиксная - обратная польская запись. прямая - может, если есть операторы разной арности - `-a` и `- a b`

Comment: Хм. А как в обратной записи интерпретировать такое: `5 7 -`? Это унарный минус или бинарный? А если так: `5 7 - *`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидный честный алгоритм — распарсить польскую запись в дерево. Имея дерево, можно рекурсивно строить любые формы записи (а также оптимизировать, компилировать и выполнять, что угодно).

Для записи

```
− 5 * 6 7
```

вы делаете следующие шаги:

1. Видите минус, аллоцируете узел бинарной операции с двумя операндами.
2. Читаете первый операнд.

   - видите `5`, это и есть первый операнд, аллоцируете для него листовой узел с константой
3. Читаете второй операнд.

   - видите `*`, аллоцируете для него узел бинарной операции с двумя операндами
   - читаете первый операнд

     - видите `6`, аллоцируете для него листовой узел с константой
     - видите `7`, аллоцируете для него листовой узел с константой

---

Для конкретной задачи можно упростить результат, и не строить дерево, а сразу выводить данные. Алгоритм будет такой:

- Прочитать один токен
- Если это константа, она и есть результат
- Если это бинарная операция, запомнить её тип, рекурсивно получить значение операндов, вывести выражение, заключив его в скобки, чтобы не думать о приоритете операторов.
- *дополните правилами для других типов узлов по вкусу*

Answer (score 2):

Если лишние скобки в результате - не проблема, то можно сконвертировать обычной рекурсией:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string source = "- * / 15 - 7 + 1 1 3 + 2 + 1 1";

        var tokens = new Queue<string>(source.Split());

        Console.WriteLine(DoConvert(tokens));
    }

    private static string[] operators = new string[] { "+", "-", "*", "/" };

    private static string DoConvert(Queue<string> tokens)
    {
        var token = tokens.Dequeue();

        if (operators.Contains(token))
        {
            return String.Format("({0} {1} {2})", DoConvert(tokens), token, DoConvert(tokens));
        }
        else
        {
            return token;
        }
    }
}
```